# PHP 7.3 Listen for Xdebug does not work in VSCode with WAMP

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I want to debug the php file using Chrome by **Listen for XDebug**
the debugger can't catch the break point and nothing shows on the browser
while **Launch currently open script** works fine

Below are my vs json and php.ini files. My WAMP server uses the port 8081 and file I want to debug is located at `E:\Softwares\Installed\wampServer\www\store`

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000,
      "pathMappings": {
        "wamp/www/": "E:/Softwares/Installed/"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9000
    }
  ]
}
```

php.ini

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart = On
xdebug.remote_enable = On
zend_extension="E:/Softwares/Installed/wampServer/bin/php/php7.3.21/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.9.6-7.3-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = Off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="E:/Softwares/Installed/wampServer/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
```

Comment: Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and share the log. It should tell where it tries to connect to (if it tries at all) and what the response is. P.S. I assume you are using Xdebug browser helper for your Chrome (that sets the Xdebug cookie that works as a "debug me" flag), right?

Comment: I was able to trigger the break point but the browser keeps loading until the debugging is finished then displays the  page. I want step by step result

Comment: [7876] Log opened at 2020-12-23 11:53:38
[7876] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
[7876] I: Connected to client. :-)
[7876] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///E:/Softwares/Installed/wampServer/www/store/test.php"

Comment: *"I was able to trigger the break point but the browser keeps loading until the debugging is finished then displays the page."* That's EXACTLY how it works. PHP/web server buffers output and it is not getting sent to your browser immediately.

Comment: is there any way to check the results  step by step thanks for the help by the way

Comment: Not sure. But try PHP output buffering functions and then get contents of the current buffer (using "evaluate expression" or whatever VSCode may have for that) -- may work. P.S. I have no idea what you are debugging, but you better have separate PHP logic and HTML generation -- much easier to debug.

Comment: "but you better have separate PHP logic and HTML generation" that's great suggestion I think I will have to do that. thanks for your help